# Why is my class Movie having an issue creating an instance of a Movie?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am trying to create an instance of a `Movie` class, so that I can add it to a list of movies, paired with a list of times that the movie is playing at. But, for whatever reason, it is saying that there is an error trying to make the instance of the movie. I think there might be an error with the constructor, because my professor wants us to have `Date releaseDate` be constant, but I am having trouble making everything work.

Here are the error messages

```
Too many initializer values
a value of type "const char" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type Movie *
initializing: cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Movie *'
```

Here is the code that I am trying to use to create the instance of `Movie` and then add it to list of movies in `cinema`:

```cpp
Movie * movie ("Superman", 1988, 11, 08);
cinema.addMovie(movie, time1);
```

Here is the `Movie` class:

```cpp
class Movie 
{
    public:
        Movie(string & name, int yyyy, int mm, int dd) : name(name), releaseDate(Date(yyyy, mm, dd)) {}; 
        const Date & getReleaseDate(); 
        // other? 
        bool operator < (Movie& r);
        bool operator == (Movie &); 
        Movie & operator ++ (); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, Movie &); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const Movie &); 

    private: 
        Movie() = default; 
        const Date releaseDate; 
        string name; 
        int rating;
};
```

Here is the `Date` class, which is housed in the `Movie` class and needed in the constructor:

```cpp
class Date 
{
    public: 
        Date(int = 0, int = 0, int = 0);
        //…. 
        // other as appropriate 
        bool operator < (Date&);
        bool operator == (Date &); 
        friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &, const Date &); 

    private:
        int day, month, year;
};
```

And the `Cinema` class, which I will ultimately want to put it into through add class:

```cpp
class Cinema
{
    public: 
        Cinema() = default; 
        Cinema(Cinema &); 
        void addMovie(Movie *, list<int> & );
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, Cinema &); 
        //Movie * operator[](int); 
        void movieRunningAt(Movie &, list<int> & ); 
        void printShowTimes(const Movie *);
        void printAll() const;

    private:
        std::list<Movie *> movies;
        map<const Movie*, list<int>> movie_times;
};
```

and `addMovie()` function in `Cinema`:

```cpp
void Cinema::addMovie(Movie * m, list<int> & li)
{
    movie_times.insert(make_pair(m, li));
}
```

Comment: Why does `Cinema` have both a `list` and a `map` containing `Movie*` pointers? You don't need the `list`

Comment: Do what your professor requires, of course, but note that const non-static data members are usually a bad idea; they disable assignment unconditionally (which can already be disabled when desired by making the whole object const).

Answer (score 2):

```
Movie * movie ("Superman", 1988, 11, 08);
```

In the above line, you are declaring a pointer-to-a-Movie (`Movie *`) rather than a `Movie` object itself. Pointers don't take constructor-arguments.

Perhaps you intended something like this instead:

```
Movie * movie = new Movie("Superman", 1988, 11, 08);
```

Comment: That did help, thank you, but now it is saying, ```"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2664 'Movie::Movie(Movie &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [9]' to 'std::string &' why does it say it is a char array when there are double quotes around superman?
"```

Comment: A *string literal* is a `const char[N]` array, where `N` is the length of the string +1 for a null terminator (so `"Superman"` = 8 chars + 1 terminator = 9). The `Movie` constructor takes the `string` param by *non-const* reference, so it requires the caller to provide an actual `string` object, the compiler can't *implicitly* convert the `const char[]` to a *temp* `string` object to satisfy that reference. Change the param to pass the `string` either *by value* (`Movie(string name, ...)`) or by *const reference* (`Movie(const string & name, ...)`), then an *implicit* conversion will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the initialization of the object. You have used a pointer but haven't initialized it. You can declare the object, initialize it and then use the pointer. Hope it helps.